# I find that when the network connection is slow, my Android application is force-closed

Tags: android

I find that when the network connection is slow, my Android application is force-closed.

I am using following code to check the internet connection

```
 public  boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) 
        {
            try
            {           
                ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                 NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();       
                Log.v("Test--",""+netInfo.isAvailable());
                if ( netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()&& netInfo.isAvailable()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
         {    
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: you need show what your doing with internet connection..

Comment: so urgent in fact, that you have put almost zero effort into asking your question.

Comment: I like how you state the issue twice, but paste no code or error log or anything

Comment: Anoop, you can edit your post and include the code in there.

Comment: try doin you network related stuff in thread other than main thread.

Comment: what is the error message you got on the log ? if you post error you got, we can understand your prob..

Answer (score 3):

You are checking if `netinfo` is null only after using it, and you probably get a NullPointerException:

```
Log.v("Test--",""+netInfo.isAvailable()); // << here
if ( netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()&& netInfo.isAvailable()) { 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: My problem is to  find a good method to check internet connection available, when url is not loading ...Help me with suitable examples...